# reCaptcha apparently identifying humans as bots

Tags: php, ajax, recaptcha, captcha

I built a simple website for someone. That site contains a contact form, which is protected with reCaptcha (invisible).

Everything was working fine, but recently the owner contacted me that some of her customers are complaining about the contact form "identifying them as bots" when they submit it.

I checked if I can reproduce the problem. I tested it in Firefox, Chrome, Edge and even Internet Explorer on 3 different devices and **in 100% of the cases it worked perfectly**.

Has anyone else had problems with reCaptcha and might be able to help me?

---

That's how I implemented reCaptcha:

I loaded the reCaptcha API with my key:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<myKey>"></script>
```

Then I initialize it:

```
grecaptcha.ready(function(){
  grecaptcha.execute("<myKey>").then(function(token){
    var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
    recaptchaResponse.value = token;
  });
});
```

In my form I got a hidden input element with the reCaptcha Response:

```
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">
```

Then with AJAX I call the php file for the mail:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $(form).attr('action'),
  data: {
    // all the data
    captcha: document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse').value
  }
});
```

And finally the PHP:

```
$secret = "<myKey>";
$response = $_POST["captcha"];

$verify = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");

$captcha_success = json_decode($verify);

if($captcha_success->success==false){
  echo "we don't like bots here";
} else if($captcha_success->success==true){
  // the mail function stuff
}
```

---

Can anyone imagine in what case the verification could fail?

Comment: By "identifying them as bots", do you mean they are being forced to complete the captcha?

Comment: @BrettGregson: v2 is only the checkbox. If you're "identified as bot", the checkbox unchecks again; there's no fallback AFAIK.

Comment: `data: {document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse').value}` needs to be `data: {captcha : document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse').value}`

Comment: @BrettGregson: No, I mean that the PHP `$captcha_success->success==false` statement fires. The users don't need to complete a captcha, since it's reCaptcha (invisible)

Comment: @Piskvor Sorry that's a typo. I did that in my code

Comment: check if its your clients-side code or the php, are you getting the token in `$_POST["captcha"]`?, or is is simply not populated, which is why it fails each time?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone My code works fine. Everytime I test it, it works as I want it to. The problem is that some customers are complaining, because the contact form returns "we don't like bots here" for them. For me it's working in every browser/device/...